# How can I reduce the size of my dropdown menu trigger heading element?

Tags: html, css

I'm making the heading for a website and I ran into a problem. On the left side of the screen I have some text and on the right side is a language select menu, using a dropdown menu. But if I hover over the whole heading, the dropdown menu expands. I only want this to happen when I actually hover over the language select. Here some code:

```css
header > h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 4%;
}

#hr1 {
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 3px;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.dropdown {
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: -57px;
    background: pink;
}

.dropdown-div {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-items {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-items {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-items > button {
    background-color: #0E3854;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-items #dropdown-item1 {
    display: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.dropdown-item {
    display: block;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
}

#dropdown-item2 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#hr2 {
    background: #FFF;
    height: 3px;
    width: 7%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: -3px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>The right side of the page</h1>
</header>
<hr id="hr1">
<div class="dropdown">
  <h1 class="dropdown-div" id="dropdown-div-text">Taal</h1>
    <div class="dropdown-items">
      <button onclick="languageSelectDutch()" class="dropdown-item" id="dropdown- 
      item1">Nederlands</button>
      <button onclick="languageSelectEnglish()" class="dropdown-item" id="dropdown- 
      item2">Engels</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the html structure is not ideal. I run the code and I added to the .dropdown class the following:
`width:100px;float:right;`
If the the dropdown element takes the whole screen it will hover across the screen. You specify `text-align:right` but the div still occupies the whole screen. The code I provided it will work but is not a great solution, it will misbehave in different viewport sizes. To do this the right way you probably need to use flexbox. Highly recommend to see this [guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: You should copy the snippet from the question down here and make modifications to demonstrate your solution.

Comment: Floats are problematic and a rather obsolete means of layout. I would use other methods.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start using a wrapper to give alignment to the dropdown. You have other layout issues to resolve, but I'm not sure of your intended outcome.

```css
header>h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 4%;
}

.dropdown-wrapper {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: -57px;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block; /* make this element shrink to contents */
}

.dropdown-div {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: pink;
}

.dropdown-items {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-items {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-items>button {
  background-color: #0E3854;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-items #dropdown-item1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.dropdown-item {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#dropdown-item2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>The right side of the page</h1>
</header>

<hr id="hr1">

<div class="dropdown-wrapper">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <h1 class="dropdown-div" id="dropdown-div-text">Taal</h1>

    <div class="dropdown-items">
      <button onclick="languageSelectDutch()" class="dropdown-item" id="dropdown- 
      item1">Nederlands</button>
      <button onclick="languageSelectEnglish()" class="dropdown-item" id="dropdown- 
      item2">Engels</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```